# One to many linq Eager load

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am working with the following technologies: C#, SQL Server, ASP.NET and Entity Framework and Linq.
I have a many to many relation , using eager load. **I want to get all the courses where a student is inscribed**. As you can see I have a one to many relation from student to inscribe table.

The model classes:

```
public class Courses
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //more properties here
     public student stud { get; set; }
}

public class Enroll
{
    [Key]
    public intId { get; set; }
    //properties here
    [Required]
    public string StudentId{ get; set; }
    public Courses Courses{ get; set; }
}
public class student{
 public intId { get; set; }
  //other properties
  public Inscripe Inscription {get;set}
}
```

This is what my controller:

```
public IEnumerable<course> GetCoursesStudent(Int studentId)
{
     //some code here to validate
     var result = _dbContext
.Enroll.Include(c => c.Courses)
.Where(c => c.StudentId == studentId)
.SelectMany(c => c.Courses).ToList();
}
```

**problem** : 
I receive an error from the SelectMany: the type aregument for method Queribly.selectMany(IQueryableExpression>> can not be infered from the usage.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please copy and paste the error.

Comment: Also, I don't think "inscribe" means what you think it means - you seem to mean "enroll".

Comment: somebody can make me know why downvote my question?? at least I can know how to improve my questions quality! do not just down vote , is like trolling.

Comment: `Courses` isn't a collection, so `SelectMany` is not appropriate.  Use `Select`.  Or make `Courses` a collection.

Comment: The reason for downvotes can be seen by hovering over the downvote button. It is not required to leave a comment, and it is certainly not "like trolling".

Comment: Indeed, no one is obligated to offer you an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The type you specified for the IEnumerable is wrong. It should be "Courses" instead of "course":

```
public IEnumerable<Courses> GetCoursesStudent(Int studentId)
{
    var result = _dbContext
        .Enroll
        .Include(c => c.Courses)
        .Where(c => c.StudentId == studentId)
        .SelectMany(c => c.Courses)
        .ToList();
}
```

And the "Courses" property of Enroll class should be an enumerable:

```
public class Enroll
{
    [Key]
    public intId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
}
```